# How to make a Node dependent coin operator?

Tags: quantum-walks

In a non-regular graph the degree of each node is different.

So, the dimension of the coin operator also needs to be changed (as the number of options the walker has to hop to adjacent nodes will be different) as opposed to for example a 2-d regular graph where coin dimensions are $C^2$ for every node.

Any idea.

Comment: Might just be me, but could you add further context as to this problem? (e.g. existing literature that's related)

Comment: You could have a coin circuit for each degree and condition it on the current node having that degree. You could generate a huge number and mod by the current degree (small bias).